# How to connect the ground in this common base schematic to a breadboard?

Tags: amplifier, ground, breadboard, common-base

I just want to know how do I connect the ground in this common base circuit. I know how to connect two DC sources but I'm confused on how to connect the ground. I have adept knowledge about the concept of ground, I just want to know how to connect the ground (0V) in this schematic to a breadboard.

[image]

Comment: How can you connect it to ground when all you have is an artist's impression of two PN junctions with three pins labeled E, B and C. What physical thing do you have that you can connect anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand the ground in this circuit or any similar circuits explaining basic concepts, you need to also look at PRACTICAL circuits using the same concepts. In this particular case, you need find a practical common-base amplifier schematic, or actually a few of them, so that you can see the various ways how this is done.  That will help you understand this "ground" concept in such circuits.
Basically, you have to do your own research and thinking, and it takes time and effort (with theoretical, conceptual and practical examples) to understand, no shortcuts.

P.S.: You keep posting very similar, almost the same questions, and you don't mark people's answers as either accepted or helpful. That's not how it works here. If people take the time and effort to answer your questions, you should take a couple seconds to show you appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi sir, I'm very sorry if I did not mark your answer as solved because I am very new to this forum. I replied thanks to your answer in one of my post to show my appreciation. I thought that you will not reply on the first thread I created so I decided to post another independent question to further clarify and for other users to give their perspectives. I posted it here before you answered my comment in my previous question. I just only want to know how to connect these grounds in real life if I encountered these circuits in real life. Sorry for disturbance.

Answer (score 0):

In most electronic circuits, particularly battery-powered circuits, the Ground symbol just indicates the point that the designer considers as "Zero Volts", and does not imply any connection to The Earth.

You are not expected to connect that "Ground" symbol to the AC Safety Ground or other external ground point.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up my confusion..